# Bound on sum of differences in a finite sequence

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Suppose we have a sequence of non-negative real numbers $m_1,...,m_N$, and let $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}m_i \leq N \cdot k.
\end{equation}

I am interested in an upper bound of the quantity of $\binom{N}{2}$ additions of differences:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i,j}^N \lvert{m_i-m_j}\rvert,
\end{equation}
with respect to $k$. Note that in the sum, if the pair $(i,j)$ is selected, then $(j,i)$ will not be repeated. I did various experiments, and turned out that $\binom{N}{2}k$ certainly works in many examples, but I am not sure if it is true or is there a proof? Also, is there any tighter bounds with respect to $k$?

Comment: Without loss of generality, you may assume $m_1 \le m_2 \le \cdots \le m_{N}$. Then you can express sum of $\binom{N}{2}$ differences into linear function. I think you can proceed from here.

Comment: @sansae, thanks for the hint. But I still have trouble. Even though I may write the sum of differences into linear function and cancel many terms, I cannot see each difference is bounded by $k$. Could you please give a stronger hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: The best possible upper bound you can give is $N(N-1)k$. 
$\hspace{1.8cm}$This is double your answer of $\binom{N}2k$.

*Proof:* WLOG, $m_1<m_2<\dots<m_n$. Then the sum does not require absolute values:
$$
\sum_{i<j}(m_j-m_i)
$$
If you were to write out all $\binom{N}2$ of those differences, and collect like terms, you would get a sum like
$$
c_1m_1+c_2m_2+\dots+c_nm_n
$$
Explicitly, $c_k$ is the number of times $m_k$ appears on the positive end of the difference, minus the number of times it appears on the negative end. With some thought, you can show
$$
c_k=(k-1)-(N-k)=2k-N-1
$$
The maximum value of $c_k$ is $c_N=N-1$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N c_km_k\le (N-1)\sum m_k\le(N-1)Nk
$$
This bound is attainable when $m_n=Nk$, and the rest of the $m_i$ ($1\le i\le N-1$) are zero.